# SMTP exception. asking for authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
    {
        Subject = "Subject",
        Body = "Body"
    };
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("demo@example.com", "Some name"));

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(message);
}
```

config

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="demo@example.com">
        <network host="****" defaultCredentials="false"  port="587" userName="****" password="****" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
 <system.web>
```

Correction. it works now. Thanks Marek

Comment: aren't you supposed to be using a gmail from address to go with the gmail smtp server settings?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that GMail is not going to allow you to send an email from a Yahoo address. However, there are also a lot of posts pertaining to issues like this and Gmail (sorry I can't find one easily enough).

Comment: i changed my email address to gmail. it still wont work. what does the message error relate to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be with `defaultCredentials` set to true.  Try setting that to false and try again.  Also, why are you setting your credentials again in code?  Gmail also requires emails to be sent via SSL (if I remember correctly) on port 587.

Just today I implemented gmail smtp in my code.  My settings and code:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="MY_GMAIL_EMAIL">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="MY_GMAIL_USERNAME" password="MY_GMAIL_PASSWORD" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>


MailMessage message = new MailMessage() {
                              Subject = "Subject",
                              Body = "Body"
                          };
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("someemail@domain.com", "Some name"));
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: Yep, port 25 is for email relays, [port 587 is for SMTP submission](http://mostlygeek.com/tech/smtp-on-port-587/comment-page-1/).

Comment: okay, i updated my whole answer!!!.. no exception is thrown, but no email is sent either

Comment: did you change your yahoo email to gmail? `<smtp from="makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk">`

Comment: if i want to send the user a link to press...can i just type it out?!? and it will become pressable..and another question , my site is not up, i want to send him a link that will connect direct to my page..how do i do this, if i dont know the address that the page will be at after i upload my site. i work in visual studio 2010

Comment: First question is simple: `message.IsBodyHtml = true;` will allow you to add regular HTML tags to your email.  The second one is also easy - use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` or `Request.Url.Host` (depending on where in the program you are - `HttpContext` is what I would use most of the time).  This will give you the URL of the site the code is running on.

Comment: hmmm... i get it..very clever